# Why cannot linear activation functions be used to approximate any function?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, activation-functions, relu

In neural networks we use nonlinear activation functions such as sigmoid, [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), etc. Using a combination of these functions (with required scaling and shifting), we manage to estimate any nonlinear function.

I understand in theoretically that we cannot obtain a function such as e<sup>x<sub>1</sub></sup>  + x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> ...(and other such nonlinear components of inputs x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>, etc.) using only linear combinations of x<sub>i</sub>'s. However, when I am thinking graphically I think that it is possible to approximate these nonlinear functions using lots of linear (scaled and shifted) linear lines and I do not understand why this is incorrect.

In case, if it is possible to approximate any function using a ReLU activation function (which is linear in the first quadrant), why is it not possible to approximate with a function completely linear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I when thinking graphically I think that it is possible to approximate these nonlinear functions using lots of linear ( scaled and shifted) linear lines and I do not understand why this is incorrect.

It's not generally incorrect, but what you are describing there is not a single function but a [**piecewise function**](https://www.math.net/piecewise-functions). For example:

$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0.1 x & \quad 0 \leq x < 0.1 \\
            0.2 x & \quad 0.1 \leq x < 0.2\\
            0.3 x & \quad ...
        \end{array}
    \right.
$

This composition is non-linear, because the input space gets transformed differently depending on $x$ (because each subfunction in the example above has a different slope). There are methods to optimize such a function as well, e.g. [piecewise linear regression](https://medium.com/databulls/piecewise-linear-regression-30b63ff8a90d).

An MLP without non-linearities is not a piecewise function, but a [**function composition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition):

$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$,

where $g$ and $f$ are two consecutive dense layers.
The difference is that if both functions $g$ and $f$ are linear, then $f \circ g$ is linear. This holds for any configuration of model parameters. Therefore, the model transforms any given input space $X$ into some output space $W$, where straight lines in the input space remain straight in the output space and can thus never model something non-linear.

> In case, if it is possible to approximate any function using Relu activation function ( which is linear on first quadrant) , why it is not possible to approximate with a function completely linear ?

**As soon as you introduce any non-linearity**, the system becomes much more expressive, because each neuron now models a non-linear function. Combining the neurons (as done by a subsequent layer) can learn combinations of these non-linear functions.

And this is where the two worlds collide: If you take a `ReLU` activation, it allows the model to actually learn something like a piecewise linear function, because of the combinations of several linear functions with different slopes that are $< 0$ only for certain input ranges. Here is a simple example of that:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.random.set_seed(4)
np.random.seed(4)

# create a dataset
xs = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
ys = xs**2 + 0.2

# create a model
m = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

# train the model
m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MAE)
m.fit(xs[:,np.newaxis], ys[:,np.newaxis], batch_size=8, epochs=20, verbose=None)

# plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 6))

ax[0].plot(xs, xs, label='model inputs')
ax[0].plot(xs, ys, label='ground truth')
ax[0].plot(xs, m(xs)[:,0], label='prediction')
ax[1].plot(xs, ys)

for n in range(m.layers[0].units):
    neuron_act = m.layers[0](xs[:,np.newaxis])[:,n]
    ax[1].plot(xs, neuron_act, color='g', label='piecewise function %d' % n)
               
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
ax[0].set_ylim((-1, 4))
ax[1].set_ylim((-1, 4))
```

[image]

The left image shows what the model has learned (green line), the right side shows the functions of the individual neurons. The more neurons you add to that first `relu`-layer, the better the approximation of the ground truth will be.

Comment: Thank you very much, great explanation and demonstration. The point is that using linear functions ( exactly, not piece-wise) and combining them in some way, we can never obtain the example function you gave right ?

Comment: Right! To achieve that, we would have to partition the function which itself is a non-linearity :)